# Writing templates without using html for ruby on rails/django

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, templates, django-templates

I hate to explicitly use html/css to build pages.  Is there a template language I can use to semantically and quickly describe the layout and content of the page so that later I can generate html and css from it?

I'm planning to use this on a django site (but I guess if such solution already exists for RoR I can always adapt it).

Thanks.

Comment: What would this look like? Are you just trying to avoid writing HTML and CSS? Sounds like you need a web-developer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [GRHML](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2008/2/15/ghrml-haml-for-genshi), which is [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) for [Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/). ([Django adapter](https://launchpad.net/django-genshi))